# customizable (open-source) wifi hotspot software?

Tags: wifi, hotspot

I wanted to know, which softwares are being used to setup customizable WiFi hostpot, on laptop.

I've heard OpenWRT - but think it's for router.  I need for Latpop, which will allow me to change the source code of Hotspot easily - i.e. to configure it to allow several different passwords, catch incorrect login attempts (incorrect handshake data) or even allow incorrect handshake data to access the Hostpot.

p.s. I use Windows, however, any OS solution is welcome. Most of programs just use OS API to enable/disable hostpot and set Password.  However, they dont touch the SYS-LOGIC itself... So, I want to change the logic of Hostpot, you may understand what i mean.

Comment: What is your Laptop's operating system?

Comment: @fossil Windows 10, but it doesnt matter, any OS solution is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would not go wrong with `CoovaChilli`. CoovaChilli is an open-source software access controller, based on the popular, but now defunct, ChilliSpot project. CoovaChilli works on Linux operating system and probably other *NIX systems too. I have not tested other operating systems.

`CoovaChilli` allows you to flexible authentication using Radius server, allowing you to customize authentication and fallback mechanisms. As you are planning to run on a laptop, you can comfortably use `FreeRadius` as Radius server.

`CoovaChilli` can be easily integrated with third party user management solution.

Checkout http://coova.github.io/CoovaChilli/

Also checkout, http://coova.github.io/CoovaChilli/chilli_query(1).html explaining you how one can integrate the `CoovaChilli` with your software.

Disclaimer: I am not promoting the `CoovaChilli` with any commercial motive. I have no commercial relationship with developers of `CoovaChilli`

Answer (score 0):

If you are a windozer, you have free options:

- [16WiFi](http://wifi.drivethelife.com/)
- [MyPublicWiFi](http://www.mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/en/index.html)
- [Winhotspot](http://www.winhotspot.com/)
- [mHotspot](http://www.mhotspot.com/)
- [Virtual Router Plus](http://virtualrouterplus.com/)
- [Vritual Router Manager](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)
- [Wi-Host](http://www.askvg.com/wi-host-freeware-to-turn-your-windows-pc-or-laptop-into-wi-fi-host-spot-to-share-internet-connection/)

If you use linux, you have other options too:

- [Chillspot](http://www.chillispot.org/)
- [CoovaChilli](http://coova.org)
- [EasyHotspot](http://easyhotspot.inov.asia/)
- [AuthNat](http://authnat.sourceforge.net/)
- [Captivair](http://thorwifi.sourceforge.net/)
- [ezRADIUS](http://ezradius.sourceforge.net)

And there are more! Hope it helps